# Re-imaging Collimated Beam

Tags: optics, education, lenses

I am trying to solve a re-imaging two lens system and I am aware of the Thin Lens Equation, $ \frac{1}{d_{image}} + \frac{1}{d_{object}} = \frac{1}{f}$ where $f$ is the focal length.

My scenario is thus:

A collimated beam goes through two positive lenses with focal lengths $f_1$ and $f_2$ (I know these, and I know the relation between them via the magnification equation $ m = -\frac{f2}{f1}$). The distance between the centers of the two lenses, T, is $ T = f_1 + f_2$. The beam hits a mirror that is some distance G away from the center of the second lens. The beam is reflected back through the lenses and forms an image at distance L from the center of the first lens. What is the distance from the first focal lens to the image in terms of $G, f_1, f_2$.

[[image: A collimated beam goes through two lenses and is reflected back. where is the image located in relation to first lens (i.e. the lens with focal length <span class=]$f_1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjlZz.png)

My attempt using the Thin Lens Formula gave:

$$ L = \frac{f_1(f_1 f_2 - f_1 G + f_2^2)}{f_2^2}.$$

I'm confused as to what affect the collimated beam condition does and if my solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is at heart a simple two lens system. The mirror can be used as a "pseudo-source", allowing for the problem to be solved in reverse (i.e. starting from the mirror and working towards lens 1) and solving for a single ray is the easiest way to do this. The collimation condition says that the distance between the two lenses is equal to the sum of their focal lengths, i.e.
$f_1 + f_2 = d_{lenses}$

There are countless examples online on how to do a simple two lens system, and the best resource I've found is probably a paper titled "Study of two-lens system with the method of Newton's lens formula" and it is available on ResearchGate.

When the beam goes through lens 2 and then lens 1, the solution is:

$ L = f_1 *  \lbrack 1 + \frac{f1}{f2} + \frac{f_1 G}{f_2^2} \rbrack $

When the beam goes through lens 1 and then lens 2, the solution is of a similar form but with the focal lengths switched around:

$L = f_2 *  \lbrack 1 + \frac{f2}{f1} + \frac{f_2 G}{f_1^2} \rbrack $