# How does the quality of the reflected light compare to the emitted light? And how do I manage this (reflected) light quality well?

Tags: optics, laser, interference, lenses, interferometry

I am designing an interferometer for an experiment. The setup consists of (1) the laser source, (2) the interferometer itself (consisting of optical components and photodetector(s)), and (3) the target object. Once the laser source emits into the interferometer setup, it first encounters a spatial filter. This spatial filter converts the low-quality, rapidly diverging beam of the laser diode into a high-quality, collimated beam. Once the beam exits the spatial filter, it enters a beam splitter. This beam splitter allows part of the beam to be emitted at the target, and part of the beam to go deeper into the interferometer setup. The interferometer then depends on light reflected back into the interferometer from the target object.

1. Light being emitted at the target object:

[image]

2. Light being reflected from the target object back into the interferometer:

[image]

One of my main concerns is managing beam quality in this setup. As I mentioned, I'm thinking of using a spatial filter and aspheric lenses at the point of emission (directly in front of the laser diode) to increase the beam quality (see slides 13/14 [here](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Circularization_of_Elliptical_Beams.pdf)). But I'm wondering about the light reflected back into the interferometer from the object: how does the quality of this reflected light compare to the spatially-filtered (again, see the slides) light being emitted from the setup (the light that is incident upon the object in the first place)? And how do I manage this (reflected) light quality well?

I have seen interferometer setups (**see edit 2 below**) that have an aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer system. The aspheric lens seems to be orientated so that the light *leaving* (being emitted from) the interferometer is focused, and the light *entering* (reflected back into) the interferometer is collimated. So, based on this design choice, I'm inferring that there does indeed seem to be some concern about collimating the returned/reflected light from the object. However, from what I can tell, doing this with my setup would defeat its purpose (the purpose of my setup), since it would then take the spatially-filtered, high quality light, and then emit a focused beam at the object, rather than just emitting my collimated, high quality beam. (**See edit 3 below**.)

I'm trying to think about how to get around this problem. One idea I had was to use two aspheric lenses (rather than one), orientated as shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571934/141502):

[image]

Using this setup, my spatially filtered, high quality light would enter the first aspheric lens, become uncollimated, and then enter a second aspheric lens, which would then re-collimate it before it leaves to be emitted at the object. Inversely, the reflected light from the object would enter the first (from the outside) aspheric lens, and then enter the second, which would collimate the reflected light before it enters the interferometry setup for the purpose of interferometry. However, I'm not sure if this idea makes sense: is the progress I made on improving the quality of the beam at the earlier point in the system with the spatial filter lost when the first aspheric lens focuses the light (in particular, is the improvement in the quality of the wavefront maintained, which, [as I understand it, is particularly important for interferometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/653239/141502))? Or, perhaps, am I going about this the wrong way, and I might actually need to place a *second* spatial filter (and the accompanying two aspheric lenses) at the aperture of the system (since, as I understand it, spatial filters do the same thing from both ends)?

As you can see, fundamentally, what I'm trying to do here is maintain good beam/light quality in all parts of the system, including for the light that is reflected from the object and back into the interferometer, in order to maximise (within reason) interferometer performance.

---

### EDIT 2

As an example, see how there's an objective lens focusing the emitted beam from the interferometer at the sample:

[image]

*(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry#Biology_and_medicine )*

And a more clear example:

[image]

*(From https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/ay/c9ay00369j/unauth )*

This is what I was referring to with regards to the single aspheric lens: the light being emitted from the interferometer is focused at the object, and the light reflected from the object back into the interferometer is collimated.

1. Light being emitted at the target object (now including an aspheric lens):

[image]

2. Light being reflected from the target object back into the interferometer (now including an aspheric lens):

[image]

---

### EDIT 3

From [this](https://www.rp-photonics.com/spotlight_2009_11_22.html) article:

> Imagine that you have a collimated laser beam which has a clean Gaussian intensity profile. Now you use a lens to focus that beam down to a small spot. Will you obtain a nice Gaussian beam shape also in the focus?
>
> I suppose that many people would indeed expect that, as they believe that the focus is basically just a demagnified copy of the original large beam. Therefore, they believe that it is sufficient to inspect the profile where it is large – which is often much easier to do than inspecting the beam around focus. (Particularly for Q-switched lasers, it is inconvenient to inspect the focus, as the intensities are very high, and it is not always trivial to attenuate a beam while preserving its profile.)
>
> Unfortunately, the described expectation is utterly wrong. Without inspecting the focus itself (or knowing the details of your beam source), you don't really know your beam. The beam profile may contain phase distortions which you cannot see by looking only at intensity profiles. While the beam is collimated, such phase distortions may have only negligible effects. Once you get to the focus, however, they become important. In particular, you may get a non-Gaussian beam shape there, and the beam radius may be significantly larger than you expect based on a calculation for Gaussian beams.

Comment: Please post a drawing of the *entire* setup. Your terms "entering" and "leaving" the interferometer don't make much sense.

Comment: In any case,  you do **not** want a spatial filter in the path of the light returning from the object, since that would remove some of the information (phase shifts) you are looking for.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ahh, yes, I suspected that that would be the case; thanks for clarifying. Anyway, I have edited my post with a diagram. The spatial filter would be directly after the laser source (before the beam splitter), so that the beam is filtered/fixed immediately. You can see the filtered beam leave, and then the reflected light enter, the interferometer aperture. My concern is what to do at this aperture in order to maximise the quality of the returned/reflected light from the object, for the purpose of interferometry. [...]

Comment: [...] As I mentioned, I have seen setups (without a spatial filter) where people place an aspheric lens at that aperture, orientated so that the beam is focused at the object and the light returning/reflected from the object is collimated. But, in this regard, my point was that doing such a thing defeats the point of the spatial filtering, since the aspheric lens will convert the filtered emission beam into a focused one.

Comment: this is too dense in my opinion. This is over thinking before having a minimally working setup. My advice is you work in steps, and first create a working interferometer on which you can measure for example length changes or any easily measureable parameter. Then you can start worrying about other aspects. For example, edit 3 is pertinent for data analysis: if you focus on sample but detect collimated beam, you might need an integral to retrieve the whole phase shift, but of course depends on what you are trying to achieve with the setup and if that is necessary at all.

Comment: and you also miss the point on "quality" from spatial filtering and what it is meant to do. All it means, is that the light going into the interferometer has low phase front distortions, which increases your chances of detecting low phase distortions in the probe beam of the interferometer. High quality is important in the reference arm and in the probing arm BEFORE interacting with the the object being probed. The aspheric lens will not affect the quality of your beam, as you seem to think, this is independent (in fact it does, but it is just a minor contribution (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) and that is why calibrations of interferometers are done prior to the experiment). If you carefully prepared the beam with an aperture, then whatever comes after, in a typical interferometer, does not change that.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thanks for the insightful comments. So is it important to have an aspheric lens to focus the beam at the target object, and then collimate the reflected light from the object, as shown in the two diagrams? Or is it fine to just have no aspheric lens there, and just emit the collimated beam from the spatial filter at the target object? How important is it to have an aspheric lens there to collimate the reflected light from the target object?

Comment: Did you already set up the spatial filter? Typically you need 2 lenses and the filter, as you focus, clip all unwanted $k$-vectors at the focus and then re-collimate the beam. I am not an expert in spatial interferometry, but I would say that using a collimated beam throughout should pose no problem.

Comment: @JoséAndrade yes, the beam will be focused from the first aspheric lens into the spatial filter pinhole, and then re-collimated by the second aspheric lens. But this is done immediately after the light is emitted from the laser source, before it enters the beam splitter. What I’m referring to here is the aspheric lens that is placed at the aperture of the interferometer, after the beam leaves the beam splitter and before it hits the target object. My point was that some interferometer setups, such as the ones in the diagrams shown, include an aspheric lens at the aperture of the […]

Comment: […] interferometer, which, as shown in the diagrams, focuses the emitted beam at the target object, and then collimates the reflected light that re-enters the interferometer. I’m asking if it matters whether I include this other aspheric lens. My target object distance varies between 10-100cm, so I’d rather not use the lens because it gives a fixed focus. On the other hand, my understanding is that, theoretically, a collimated beam is always at focus, so I want to know if I can just use the collimated beam from the spatial filter, coming straight out of the beam splitter, rather than […]

Comment: I understood which lens you were speaking of. It just looked like you had a single lens for the filtering. Like I said, without lens, I guess there should be no problem and you have direct access to phase distortions.

Comment: […] include another aspheric lens. But this has the downside of not having an aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer (at the gap shown in my drawn diagrams), which means that the reflected light is not collimated, so I want to know if this is a problem.

Comment: @JoséAndrade hmm, ok. So it doesn’t matter if the reflected light from the target object is collimated or not before it enters the interferometer?

Comment: depends on many things. The way the setup you showed works, because its probably a diffuse reflection, uses the lens to guarantee both accuracy of the probing site and to be able to collect as much light as possible. If I were you, I would look into holography and what constraints what, because it seems to me that this would help you a lot understanding where your limitations are depending on your application. I would also suggest reading a lot of literature, on articles doing the same thing as you want, and first try to replicate their results, and only after that, debug your setup.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thank you very much for the advice. It seems to me that, as you said, at this point, I just need to put together some simple experimental configuration, and then modify it depending on the results. I appreciate your help.