# Since a collimated beam is always in focus, can't I simply just emit a collimated beam over the varying distances as the target object moves?

Tags: optics, laser, interference, lenses, interferometry

I am designing an interferometer for an experiment. The setup consists of (1) the laser source, (2) the interferometer itself (consisting of optical components and photodetector(s)), and (3) the target object. Once the laser source emits into the interferometer setup, it first encounters a spatial filter. This spatial filter converts the low-quality, rapidly diverging beam of the laser diode into a high-quality, collimated beam. Once the beam exits the spatial filter, it enters a beam splitter. This beam splitter allows part of the beam to be emitted at the target, and part of the beam to go deeper into the interferometer setup. The interferometer then depends on light reflected back into the interferometer from the target object.

1. Light being emitted at the target object:

[image]

2. Light being reflected from the target object back into the interferometer:

[image]

I have seen interferometer setups that have an aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer system. The aspheric lens seems to be orientated so that the light leaving (being emitted from) the interferometer is focused, and the light entering (reflected back into) the interferometer is collimated. This is illustrated in these diagrams:

[image]

*(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry#Biology_and_medicine )*

[image]

*(From https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/ay/c9ay00369j/unauth )*

1. Light being emitted at the target object (now including an aspheric lens):

[image]

2. Light being reflected from the target object back into the interferometer (now including an aspheric lens):

[image]

However, the problem is that my target object distance, from the aperture of the interferometer to the target object, **varies** between 10-100cm. This means that, if the optics at the aperture of the interferometer give the emitted beam a fixed focus, as an aspheric lens would, the beam would be out of focus when incident upon the target object. And, so, this would decrease the performance of my interferometer. Therefore, I don't want optics at the aperture of the interferometer that result in a fixed focus (such as an aspheric lens), since that wouldn't properly focus the beam for a varying-distance target.

But I had an idea to get around this. Since I'm using a spatial filter with aspheric lenses (see slides 13/14 [here](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Circularization_of_Elliptical_Beams.pdf)) immediately after the laser source in order to collimate the beam and get it to a high quality state, and since a collimated beam is, as I understand it, always in focus, can't I simply just emit the collimated beam over the varying distances as the target object moves (as shown in the first two diagrams), rather than having the fixed-focus optics (the aspheric lens) at the aperture of the interferometer (as shown in the last two diagrams)? It seems to me that, as long as the beam is relatively well-collimated (which it should be from the spatial filter), and as long as the distance isn't too far (which, for 10-100cm, it shouldn't be), this would mean that the beam will be in relatively good focus when incident upon the target object.

---

This question is related to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656024/141502) question.

Comment: Good source of information about optical topics - [RP Photonics Encylcopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html)

Comment: Note your 1st example is from an OCT system and uses a non-coherent source.  If your range is 10cm to 100cm you may be better off with a 2 camera 3D imaging system.  The OCT system is not simple. it requires Fourier transforms of the detector data.

Comment: @PhysicsDave what do you mean by a "2 camera 3D imaging system"? I'm not doing OCT – it was just an example diagram.

Comment: just google "2 camera 3D scanner" ... its big business for the 3D printer industry.  You are new to cameras and sensors and spectrometers and interferometers and time of flight systems and 3D scanners and all the other wonderful optical systems .... it is a real mixed bag with every system carefully tailored to the application and and every system very limited to its application.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Hmm, but what does this have to do with my question?

Comment: "However, the problem is that my target object distance varies between 10-100cm", I assume your object varies in size by 90cm?  This sounds like a 3d scanner opportunity not one for an interferometer.

Comment: @PhysicsDave I'll be more specific: the object itself is stationary, but its structure is non-uniform, so some points will be close to the interferometer (10cm) and others will be farther (100cm). But this application requires interferometry for the purpose of structural testing, so I don't understand where the cameras are coming from.

Comment: OK so the structure will deform slightly, like micrometers, and you want to detect that? And you want to scan many points on the structure ?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes, that's right, but I only want to scan one point at a time. It's a typical interferometry structural testing experiment – what's known as vibrometry.

Comment: @PhysicsDave So the point is that, if I had an aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer, the focus would be fixed (based on the focal length of the lens), which means that, as I target different points on the object, the point that I'm targeting will quickly no longer be in focus. On the other hand, having an aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer will, as I understand it, cause the light reflected from the object to become collimated (due to its biconvex geometry) as it enters the interferometer, but I'm not sure how necessary/beneficial this is. [...]

Comment: [...] So this leads to my question about whether I can just dispense with the aspheric lens at the aperture of the interferometer and just emit the collimated beam from the beam splitter. My understanding is that a collimated beam is always in focus, so, even though I can't focus it to a small spot size at the surface of the object, I wonder if it might still be ok (although, as I said, I think I lose the benefit of having the reflected light from the target object collimated when it enters the interferometer); and that is what my questions revolve around.

Comment: IMO - What you are trying to do is surface interferometry (?) and there are many expensive systems that do this.  A DYI system should be possible but still not simple.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes, it's just an interferometer. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer

Comment: https://www.nist.gov/image/interferometer-compositejpg  this is an example  of a simple interferometer ... not using lenses. If you use a laser 1um and if your object displaces 100um then you need to be able to process the data so as to count how many times the interference repeated itself ... this is why the systems are expensive.

Comment: the link is laser doppler .... so its giving speed not just displacement? is this what you need?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes, I'm aware of all this, but this is separate from my specific question here.

Comment: @ThePointer I've deleted my answer because I realize now this is more of a "design review" than a single Physics SE question about optics. I'd recommend that you delete all the other images and instead just draw one simple diagram of exactly what is necessary for your question. *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @uhoh. I have edited my question and made improvements, including improvements to the diagrams. The last paragraph contains my question.

Comment: Where is the detector in your setup? I don't see it.    And what kind of detector is it?

Comment: I think your question might be ill-defined.   I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  You mention vibrometry, I never heard of that but 60 seconds of Google research suggests to me that your set up is not up to the task.  but I may be wrong.

Comment: @garyp The detector is irrelevant for this question. I'm not trying to be rude (I recall that you've been helpful in answering some of my questions in the past, and you're definitely very knowledgeable (much more knowledgeable than I) when it comes to optics/photonics), but, given what you've said here, it seems to me that this might be outside your area of knowledge.

Comment: Well, in my 40+ years as a physicist involved in optics I've used and constructed a handful of interferometers (including an OCT system).   I think I just don't understand what you are trying to do,

Comment: @garyp In that case, it must be me. It's difficult to word a comment on the internet so that it doesn't sound rude (no matter how I read it, it sounds arrogant and rude), so I apologise for that. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: @garyp As you said, this is a vibrometry experiment. The "target object" is a structure, such as a concrete wall/slab, a statue, some artefact, etc. In such a situation, we want to perform interferometry (vibrometry) on different points of the structure. But we cannot move the target object, and we also cannot constantly move around the interferometer itself so that the beam is always in focus at the point of incidence with the target object (assuming a fixed focus). [...]

Comment: [...] So as we scan the interferometer beam over the structure (say, by scanning points higher than the level at which the interferometer device is), the distance between the interferometer and the target object (at the point our beam is incident) is actually changing (in this example, increasing). This leads to the problem I mentioned in my question: building an interferometer with a fixed focus will mean that our incident emitted beam will be out of focus at the object. And this then leads to my question in the last paragraph. Does that clarify things?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could just use a collimated beam exiting from the interferometer.  However, you don't clearly state what is the "aperture" of the interferometer. I assume you mean the arm that leaves the beamsplitter cube at 3 oclock, this is commonly called the "test arm".  But, if you use a collimated beam, there are a lot of issues that may prevent the interferometer from doing what you want it to do. If the target region where the test arm beam hits has multiple regions that differ in height by several wavelengths, then the signal back to the interferometer will consist of not just one, but several wavefronts. These multiple wavefronts may (i.e. likely will) constructively or destructively interfere. This means you'll get a mixed result for the interference signal. You will sacrifice spatial resolution in the direction perpinducular to the probe beam.

If the target region where the test arm beam hits has multiple regions that differ in angle, the return beams will be angularly dispersed going back to the interferometer. They may not make it through the interferometer or they may not hit the detector.

If your source has very low temporal coherence, you'll have to move the reference arm in z in order maintain interference between the test and reference arms. This is what most OCT setups do.   In general, any interferometric measurement device (whether OCT or not) is a compromise between resolution and range. I would recommend looking in the literature to find how people configured systems that measured the range you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have classified the "aperture of the interferometer" as the hole/gap/opening (at 6 o'clock) that the beam exits to hit the target object and then re-enters through. Sorry for any confusion. Does this change your answer?

Comment: And, to be clear, the "test arm" (the part of the beam the leaves the beamsplitter at 3 o'clock) goes deeper into the interferometer and only encounters optical elements and photodetectors, so those surfaces are uniform. However, the target surface would not be completely uniform in terms of differing in height by several wavelengths – it is not, say, a mirror. [...]

Comment: [...] But, even so, interferometers are often used for distanced testing of non-uniform materials/structures, such as in non-destructive testing, where something like concrete would be highly non-uniform by our metric of differing in height by several wavelengths, so I'm not sure how much of an obstacle that would be in practice.

Comment: Your nomenclature is still not clear to me. Consider the beamsplitter as the center of the interferometer.  The 12 oclock exit is the reference arm. The 3 oclock is the test arm. The 6 oclock direction from the beamsplitter is the detector arm.

Comment: A vibrometer (laser interferometer used to measure vibration) such as the Polytec OFV series, focuses the light to a point. So for example, the mid-range device has a 25 micron spot at a working distance of 200 mm. The spec sheet does not say explicitly, but I suspect for a given spot size the system can only tolerate a set surface roughness.

Comment: Yes, the detector arm (the 6 o'clock beam) is the one that I'm classifying as leaving the "aperture of the interferometer" – the aperture being the opening/gap.

Comment: Which figure are you referring to?  In the drawings that the OP has done, the 3 o'clock position is the reference arm.

Comment: @garyp Yes, after checking some notes, my understanding is that the **reference arm** is the optical path that the light takes after the main splitting surface until it interferes with the light from the measurement arm, whereas the **measurement arm** is the optical path of the light after the main splitting surface that travels to and from the measurement target before interfering with the light from the reference arm, so the beam at 3 o'clock would be the reference arm.